# how to make rpmbuild automatically generate require >= and not =

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I `rpmbuild` a package and afterwards I find that it requires `python(abi) = 2.5`  .  I don't want to use

```
AutoReqProv: no
```

to suppress generation of requirements completely, I just want to make it require `python(abi) >=` as I think this makes more sense.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The auto generated dependencies in rpm are written to stdout
to be read by rpm to include in a package.

The helper scripts are configured through macros, and
one can invoke a helper, and then post filter with
something like sed to change the dependencies read by rpm.